# Installing packages from source in renv

Tags: r, install.packages, rtools, renv

I need to install a package from source in renv. I can install packages from binaries in renv no problem. I can also install packages from both source & binary outside renv no problem. I am doing this within Rstudio

The error (below) makes me think it cant find the compiler. Digging around I found a thread about this that says renv cant find Rtools and then you need to run `renv:::renv_scope_rtools()` to resolve this but this just gives the message FAIL and the problem remains. Can anyone help?

thanks

```
install.packages("xfun")
Retrieving 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/xfun_0.37.tar.gz' ...
    OK [file is up to date]
Installing xfun [0.37] ...
    FAILED
Error installing package 'xfun':
================================

* installing *source* package 'xfun' ...
** package 'xfun' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"c:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c base64.c -o base64.o
sh: line 1: gcc: command not found
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:253: base64.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xfun'
* removing 'D:/Dropbox/project X/renv/staging/3/xfun'
```

Comment: If you run `Sys.which("gcc")` does a path get returned? What commands specifically do you run before `install.packages()` that make the function fail?

Comment: Sys.which("gcc") yields gcc ""

Comment: as for which commands make it fail -I think anything that puts me in a renv project (e.g renv.init or opening up a renv project)

Comment: Did you run `Sys.which("gcc")` within the renv or outside? Is there a difference? When you install `xfun` from source outside of `renv`, what's the full output? Is it using a different compiler? Do you have an `.Rprofile` file that configures rtools paths?

Comment: I get the same answer whether I run `Sys.which("gcc")` within or outside renv (which surprised me).

Comment: Actually i think i made a mistake. I cant install from source at the moment in Rstudio (only in the raw R gui). So maybe its not a renv problem? but an rstudio problem?

Comment: Though (outside renv) `Sys.which("make")` tields `C:\\rtools40\\urs\\bin\\make.exe` so it knows where rtools is?

Comment: What version of R are you running? It looks like 4.2. But your RTools path looks like Rtools for R 4.0. If you update one, you usually need to update the other. I don't have access to a windows machine at the moment so I'm not sure what compiler the different packages install. But I would make sure you have the correct version of RTools installed for your R version.

Comment: I've installed Rtools for R4.2 now but i am still struggling. Could i move this to a chat (as doesnt belong under the inital question heading anymore) and see if you can help?